# Chrome does not auto-fill forms from Keychain after update

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keychain

When I installed Google Chrome updates, it broke the Keychain integration. Now, it does not auto-fill any HTML forms (i.e. the saved username/passwords in Keychain.app).

Answer (score 2):

The problem solved itself. I just had to restart Chrome.

Why did that happen? It seems to me that Chrome asked to restart (because it had found new updates), so I restarted it. Then it lost connection with the Keychain. I went to "About" and it showed me to restart again. I did — and everything was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar, somewhat converse issue, where Chrome no longer autofilled passwords after resetting the Keychain. Restarting or updating Chrome didn't help.

I resolved it by completely signing out and back into Chrome.

This was the top Google result I found, so leaving this here for anyone with the same issue.